# Чтение из файла fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Вот у меня есть задание, знаю что легче через структуру FILE, но задание - сделать с fstream. Записываем информацию про студентов: имя, группа, оценки по 5 предметам в файл. И читаем из файла. (функция по цифре 3 ещё не реализовал).

У меня не читает из файла - ничего не происходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
string name1;
struct school {
  string name;
  string group;
 char subject[5];
  };

void create_array (school* &arr, int size) {
  arr = new school[size]; //создание массива
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
    cout<<"_ Student #"<<i+1<<" _"<<endl;
    cout<<"Name: ";
    cin>>arr[i].name;
    cout<<"Group: ";
    cin>>arr[i].group;
    cout<<"< Marks >"<<endl;
    cout<<"-Math: ";
    cin>>arr[i].subject[0];
    cout<<"-English: ";
    cin>>arr[i].subject[1];
    cout<<"-Chemistry: ";
    cin>>arr[i].subject[2];
    cout<<"-History: ";
    cin>>arr[i].subject[3];
    cout<<"-Literature: ";
    cin>>arr[i].subject[4];
    cout<<endl;
    } 
}

void write_array (school* &arr, int size) { //вывод в файл
  ofstream out("info.txt"); 
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
    out<<arr[i].name<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].group<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].subject[0]<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].subject[1]<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].subject[2]<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].subject[3]<<endl;
    out<<arr[i].subject[4]<<endl;
    } 
}

void read_array (school* &arr) { //вывод из файла
int i=0;
int k=0;
ifstream in("info.txt");
while (!in.eof()) k++;
arr = new school[k/7]; //создание массива
  while (!in.eof()) {  
    in>>arr[i].name; cout<<"flag";
    in>>arr[i].group;
    in>>arr[i].subject[0];
    in>>arr[i].subject[1];
    in>>arr[i].subject[2];
    in>>arr[i].subject[3];
    in>>arr[i].subject[4];
    cout<<"Name: "<<arr[i].name;
    cout<<"Group: "<<arr[i].group;
    cout<<"< Marks >"<<endl;
    cout<<"-Math: "<<arr[i].subject[0]<<endl; 
    cout<<"-English: "<<arr[i].subject[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"-Chemistry: "<<arr[i].subject[2]<<endl;
    cout<<"-History: "<<arr[i].subject[3]<<endl;
    cout<<"-Literature: "<<arr[i].subject[4]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    i++;
    } 
}


void search_array (school* &arr, int size) {
  bool flag=0; //поиск в массиве
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
      if (arr[i].subject[j]<=2) {
        cout<<arr[i].name<<"\t\t"<<arr[i].group<<endl;
        flag=1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (flag==0) {
    cout<<"no students"<<endl;
  }
}

void delete_array (school* &arr) {
  delete [] arr;
}

int main() {
  school* arr1;
  int size=1; 
  int f=1;
  cout<<"1-Read info"<<endl;
  cout<<"2-Write info"<<endl;
  cout<<"3-Add info"<<endl;
  cout<<">>";
  cin>>f;
  switch (f) {
    case 1:
      read_array(arr1);
      break;
    case 2:
      cout<<"Number of students: ";
      cin>>size;
      cout<<endl;
      create_array(arr1, size);
      write_array(arr1, size);
      break;
    case 3:
      cout<<"hello";
      break;
    default:
      read_array(arr1);
  }

  cout<<"------------------------";
  cout<<endl<<"Students with mark \"2\":"<<endl;
  search_array(arr1,size);
  delete_array(arr1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы увидеть проблему запишите информацию (2-Write info), а потом попробуйте прочитать (1-Read info)

Answer (score 0):

Вы открываете файл(к тому  же не проверяете открыт ли он) и в цикле проверяете достигли ли конца файла? Естественно нет: вы еще в начале, и получаете бесконечный цикл:

```
void read_array (school* &arr) { //вывод из файла
int i=0;
int k=0;
ifstream in("info.txt");
while (!in.eof()) k++; //это уберите
```

что вы хотели сделать в цикле я даже не попытался понять...